# Is it acceptable to solicit money on a user profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, abuse

I've just seen a user profile page which contains the following text:

> Donations are welcome via Paypal. Paypal account is the same as my email address.

There's no context to suggest this has anything to do with supporting the user's favourite cause - it's a direct request for money.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: He just copied and pasted the text from his website where he developed a tool it seems

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No one is making you give that user money.

As long as it is not against the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), anything goes on personal user profiles.

Answer (score 37):

Sure. Some users have Amazon Wish Lists in their profile. Nobody is forcing you to donate/pay/buy anything. If you feel generous enough to reward someone for their help, go right ahead. If not, feel free to ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

I feel this same question can be applied to any answer someone posts as a response to a question... You don't have to apply the solution that was offered.

["Solicitation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solicitation) is something done actively, if a user asks you for money in exchange for his help, that would be a problem.

In effect, this website encourages users to Solicit each other for votes in exchange for answers, which is perfectly acceptable.